# Simple "yes / no" question. Uncertain how to analyze the results

Tags: binomial-distribution, survey

I am in the midst of conducting a study which compares content in a printed catalog of records to content in a much larger online catalog of similar records. I have randomly selected 50 entries from the printed catalog and searched the online catalog to see if there are exact matches for these records. The results are 44 matches ("Yesses"), 6 non-matches ("Nos").  My hypothesis is that a significant number of records from the printed catalog will not be included in the online catalog. I have very, very little experience with statistical analysis and am unsure how to proceed. I appreciate any help or suggestions anybody can give me.

Comment: Can you state your hypothesis in plain English (without using statistical jargon like "significant" -- which doesn't belong in a hypothesis)? Please note that hypotheses are about unobserved populations, not observed samples, so measures like "number of" generally don't belong in hypotheses either.

Comment: Thank you. I was using "significant" in a generic sense. But I understand what you are saying. My hypothesis, then, is: Data from the printed catalog is not present in the online catalog.

Comment: Again, that's easy. As soon as you find even one item fulfilling that criterion, you can conclude that it is the case that "Data from the printed catalog is not present in the online catalog". If you don't find any, you can't conclude that.

Comment: Thank you again, Glen_b. I am clearly very inexperienced at this. I   am hoping that by taking a random sample of 50, I can make some intelligent conclusions as to what percentage of the printed catalog is not included in the online catalog. I have no preconceived notions regarding the size of this percentage -- I believe it's "substantial" in the general sense that it's more than just a few isolated omissions.

Comment: Ah, that's a very different thing. Yes, you certainly can do something with that, but that's estimation (a point estimate and confidence interval type of problem), not a hypothesis test. Drop the word 'hypothesis' from your question and edit it to discuss what it now seems you actually want to find out from the data, written as far as possible in plain terms.

Comment: Thank you. This is a work in progress for me and a learning experience to say the least. I've not worked with any kind of measures beyond mean, median, mode in quite some time. Your comments and those from Wayne (below) have helped me think this through.

Answer (score 2):

If you chose your 50 entries at random from the printed catalog, then you can say that approximately 12% of your printed catalog entries don't appear online. (That is the 6 *No* are 12% of the 50 entries you looked for.)

The percentage has some amount of uncertainty since it's only a sample of the entries, so it's common to calculate a range of percentages, at some level of confidence. The [Wikipedia article on the Binomial Proportion Confidence Interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) has a good explanation in its first paragraph, given the choices of methods listed I'd skip down to the Bayesian alternative, the Jeffreys Interval. I believe this is calculated in R by:

```
> round (qbeta (c(0.025, 0.975), 0.5 + 6, 0.5 + 44), 2)
[1] 0.05 0.23
```

where the 0.025 and 0.975 represent the 95% significance interval, and you have 6 *Missing* and 44 *Found*. If I've done it correctly the answer is that there's a 95% confidence that the percentage of entries missing from the online catalog is in the range of 5% to 23%.

So the actual percentage of missing entries could be as low as 5% (and you got unlucky in your sample) or as high as 23% (more than 1 in 5), with a 95% chance that the actual percentage would fall within this range. (And therefore a 5% chance that the actual percentage would be less than 5% or more than 23%.) If you had looked for 200 random entries and 24 were missing, this would narrow the 95% interval to 8% to 17% -- four times the data to cut the interval in half.

This all depends on your experiment conforming to the requirements for using a Binomial distribution. For example, it assumes that the missingness of any two pages you chose are independent of each other. (That's why randomly choosing your entries is so important.)

There's no test to say if the number of missing entries is "significant". That's a matter of practical significance as determined by experts or decision makers.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough but succinct explanation. I have examined the section of the wikipedia article you reference and believe I'm making some sense of it. A colleague had suggested using Chi Square goodness of fit test, but I did not see how I could use this method. Thanks again.

Comment: Basically, I'm using the Beta distribution, which is a curve that is used in statistics to reflect a distribution between 0 and 1 (0% and 100%). You don't need any of this if your reply to Glen_b's comment is totally correct. But what I've done is useful if you want to talk about a range of percentages that your sample might imply, at which point you or your boss or someone can decide if that's a "significant" number of missing entries. (I.e. if something needs to be done about it.)

Comment: A discussion of the range of percentages my sample may imply is exactly what I have in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: Small comment about the R calculation: there is a package `binom` which implements a bunch of different way to calculate binomial confidence interval calculations. `binom.confint (6, 50)` gives a list and e.g. `binom.bayes (6, 50)` the Jeffreys interval discussed above (according to the maintainer, it will change to Laplace prior but the difference is not of practical importance here).